# image (noninlineshape) from Word to clipboard to file

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, interop, clipboard

I have a Word document (referred to as "doc" in the code below) with a bunch of .jpg images. Some of them have text wrapped around them (= Shapes), some of them don't (= InlineShapes). I am able to save the InlineShapes like so:

```
InlineShape ils = doc.InlineShapes[1];
ils.Select();
application.Selection.Copy();
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap)) {
    Image image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
        image.Save("c:\\image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

But if I try to get the other ones by replacing the first two lines with these –

```
Shape s = doc.Shapes[1];
s.Select();
```

– it won't work. And if I check the formats with "data.GetFormats()" I notice that Bitmap isn't listed, which explains why it doesn't work. Instead it lists the "Office Drawing Shape Format". I suppose that I should try to convert the Shape to a InlineShape somehow, but I haven't been able to make it work. When I try to do it like this –

```
s.ConvertToInlineShape();
```

– I get an "invalid parameter" exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem seems to have been that I tried to convert it at the wrong time. If I loop through all Shapes and convert them before trying to do anything else it works fine.

```
int number = doc.InlineShapes.Count;
MessageBox.Show(number.ToString()); // 0 to begin with

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape s in doc.Shapes) {
    MessageBox.Show(s.Type.ToString());
    if (s.Type.ToString() == "msoTextBox") {
        MessageBox.Show(s.TextFrame.TextRange.Text);
    } else if (s.Type.ToString() == "msoPicture") {
        s.ConvertToInlineShape();
    }
}

number = doc.InlineShapes.Count;
MessageBox.Show(number.ToString());  // Now it's 1 as it should be

InlineShape ils = doc.InlineShapes[1];
ils.Select();
application.Selection.Copy();

IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap)) {
    Image image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
    image.Save("c:\\image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```